# How to connect to a peer in ethereum and then run contract on ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, remix, contract-deployment, nodes, web3-providers

I have developed a smart contract and run it with remix in cases of javascript vm and web3 provider. 
Now, I want to run it such that my computer to be connected to real ethereum network. 
I think in case of using web3 provider in remix, I am not connected really to ethereum and it's like a simulation, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

To run it on main network of Etherum You need to do it using MyEther Wallet or MetaMask.

- First Download Myetherwallet (it will take time to sync to main Etherum network) . So be patient
- If you want to just Test your Smart Contract then I would suggest you do it using "Ropsten Test Network" which can be switched to under Development Tab in MyEther wallet App.(Even this needs to be Synced)
- For Deploying your Smart Contract you would be needing some Ether , so for that use Ropsten faucet .
- Now that you have your Account set up and some Ethers in your account ,start Deploying your contract
- Make Sure you are not on Main Etherum Network but on Ropsten Test Network which is similar to Main Etherum Network but for Testing smart Contract.
  Hope it helps.